# How do I restore a hard drive that Is encrypted (errors when using go wipe everything)

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, encryption, restore

Years ago I encrypted my hard drive using true crypt I believe, and (warning, I have literally zero idea what I am talking about so cut a girl some slack and avert your eyes if that type of thing triggers you).

At the time I believe it I was only able to mount the partition by clicking a file on This USB drive I had which is now nowhere to be found.

I just want to reset it but I’ve googled for some options and everything I’ve tried doesn’t work. Any time I try to delete sda5 it recognizes that it’s there but then gives me an error about notBeingto update the kernel and tells me to restart.

When I restart it Says something like no such partition and goes to grub rescue but the couple tutorials I followed to fix it at that point don’t work (also I have no idea what I’m doing as I mentioned).

So then I reinstall Ubuntu and I’m right back where I started. It’s like half the space on the hard drive or I wouldn’t care.

Please help! Willing to have someone access remotely if anyone is interested to see it through experienced eyes

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! Could you post a screenshot of gparted?

Comment: And some more information would be helpful: Are you trying to recover any data on the encrypted drive, or just reformat/repartition it? Is it supposed to be a system drive or only a data partition?

Comment: You have to be more precise for us being able to help you. Edit your post: fix errors and describe you actions and their results precisely.